# Print number one by one using setInterval, I get Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I want to print numbers 1 to 4 one by one following is my code:

**Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var b=1;
function cal(){

$('#print').html(b + '<br/>');
b++;
};
setInterval("cal()",5000);
})
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="print"></div>
```

But it is not working, shows the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cal is not defined

Why is that and how could I fix it?

Comment: A tip: "its not working" is not a very useful report. If it was working, you wouldn't be asking a question on SO. This is an easy question, but describing explicitly what breaks down, in which way and when is a good habit to get into. To help with that, it's useful to learn about the JavaScript console, about `console.log()`, about breakpoints and other wonderful debugging features of modern web browsers.

Comment: @Amadan Improved the question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
var b = 1;
function call() {
    $('#print').append(b + '<br/>');
    b++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (b < 5) call();
    },5000);
};
call();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/Ffu5K/3/)**

Comment: thanks for help budy but i want break `<br>` afetr every number

Answer (score 3):

### The fix

#### How to use `setInterval`

This is the *right way* (to be explained later) to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval):

```
setInterval(cal, 5000);
```

#### A possible way to write this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var b = 0;
    function cal() {
        b++;
        $('#print').html(b + '<br/>');
        if (b === 4) {
            clearInterval(to);
        }
    };
    var to = setInterval(cal, 5000);
});​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GMs8U/2/)

Of course there is still place for improvement, for example you could cache `$('#print')`. You don't need to fetch it everytime.

```
...
var $print = $('#print'); //save it to a variable
function cal() {
    b++;
    $print.html(b + '<br/>'); //use the cached version
    ...
```

---

### The problem

#### String instead of function -> `eval`!

While you can technically [pass a string to `setInterval` as its first parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Syntax), it is equal to using `eval`. As we know, [`eval` is evil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!), only use it if you really know what you're doing. The same applies to `setTimeout`. No matter [what you have seen on w3schools](http://w3fools.com/#js_timing) and other outdated resources, you should not pass strings to these method. Pass a function.

#### The scope for `eval` with `setInterval`

One of the problems of using `eval` with `setInterval()` is that it tries to run your code in the string in the global scope, and that is why you get the error. `setInterval` is defined on `window`, and runs in the scope of that. You are in the scope of the closure passed to `document.ready()`, and the function is defined in this scope. `eval` tries to find it in the global scope, where it does not exist.

Comment: @Amadan Omg, thanks a lot. That's a funny mistake when you are explaining how to use `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than provide a string reference to the `cal()` function, give the `setInterval` the function reference itself:

```
var b = 1;    
function cal() {
    $('#print').html(b + '<br/>');
    b++;
};
setInterval(cal, 1000);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr7jg/)

---

Also, your current code will continue to call the interval after 4 iterations, so it's a little wasteful. You could change this to a for loop with a delay, or destroy the reference to the timer after 4 iterations, like this:

```
var b = 1;    
function cal() {
    $('#print').html(b + '<br/>');
    b++;
    if (b > 4)
        clearInterval(timer);
};
var timer = setInterval(cal, 1000);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr7jg/1/)